# How to use regexpatch with packages loading xpatch?

Tags: xpatch, l3regex, enotez

I have come to love the `regexpatch` package.

However, the `enotez` package loads `xpatch`, and it seems you cannot load both `xpatch` and `regexpatch`. So how do I resolve this? Can I load `regexpatch` and mark `xpatch` as loaded at the same time?

```
\documentclass{article}
% Features request?
% \PassOptionsToPackage{xpatch}{useregexpatch}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{enotez}
%\usepackage{regexpatch}
\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

One thing I was thinking about was to define an option in the `xpatch` package that would allow loading it, effectively skipping all the definitions. Then a user of `regexpatch` could issue `\PassOptionsToPackage{xpatch}{useregexpatch}` and easily load all packages requiring `xpatch`.

Comment: Is `\expandafter\def\csname ver@xpatch.sty\endcsname{a}` a valid solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly `regexpatch` provides all the commands of `xpatch`, with the same syntax and result, as `xpatch` itself (and additional `regex` varieties of the commands). So that would mean that it is indeed valid to pretend `xpatch` is loaded with your solution.

Comment: `enotez` used to use `xpatch` but it doesn't use it any more. I removed the unnecessary package loading and just sent an update to CTAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enotez` doesn't load `xpatch` in its current version so the MWE runs flawlessly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{enotez}[2019/10/12]% use v0.10a or newer
\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```